# How to get rid of wermgr.exe duplicates

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I open some applications, a `wermgr.exe` process launches and bugs my Windows.

As example: I am writing this topic and the Windows are just losing focus, so I have to press mouse button on this text every 3 seconds.

This is my clipboard when I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on random place.

```
[Window Title] Nessus 
[Main Instruction] Nessus has stopped working 
[Content] Windows is checking for a solution to the problem... 
[Cancel]
```

There are always 5-10 instances of wermgr. I had Nessus a longtime ago, but I removed it.

[image]

Event log:

[image]

Comment: Despite uninstalling [Nessus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessus_(software)), I guess there are still traces left. The [wermgr.exe](http://www.tech-faq.com/wermgr-exe.html) is only a symptom, not the cause. As first step, I would use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check what gets automatically started

Comment: Nope, Nessus isn't installed.

Comment: Wermrg.exe is Windows Error Reporting Manager, it's cleaning up after an error. As nixda says it's not the cause, it's a symptom.  Check your Event Logs for error information. And obviously Nessus (or parts of it) still exist and/or are being referenced, else you wouldn't get an error regarding it. ;) Did you do as nixda suggested and check your startup entries with AutoRuns?

Comment: Wermgr opens on opening apps, not on startup, so I didn't.

Comment: Event Logs screenshot http://prntscr.com/5mbfv1

Comment: You should be worried about that process crashing instead of Windows Reporting Manger doing it's work. Try finding the 'nessusd.exe' file and try renaming it, and see what happens.

Comment: I can't :( http://prntscr.com/5mmaux